# Couldn't recreate a crash issue from play console

Tags: android, flutter, location

A crash issue is reported on play console with the following log,

```
Exception java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface k2.b, but class was expected (declaration of 'k2.b' appears in base.apk)
  at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocation.setActivity (FlutterLocation.java)
  at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService.setActivity (FlutterLocationService.java)
  at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.dispose (LocationPlugin.java)
  at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.detachActivity (LocationPlugin.java)
  at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.onDetachedFromActivity (LocationPlugin.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.detachFromActivity (FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDetach (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onDestroy (FlutterActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy (Activity.java:8748)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy (Instrumentation.java:1421)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:5521)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:5570)
  at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute (DestroyActivityItem.java:47)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute (ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:176)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2399)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:238)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:357)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8094)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:957)
```

Couldn't recreate the issue while testing the app on my own both in debug mode and release mode.

After researching found the issue is with the [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package so I've replaced that with [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator).

Im not sure will that fix the issue since I couldn't recreate. Is there any way to either recreate the issue or to get more details about the crash?